# How do I add a class to basic ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm wanting to show the page title on my show action of the controller, similar to I have on my index controller, but without a link to the page. The following code is the working code I have on my index page:

```
<%= link_to @page.title, page_path(@page), class: "h1" %>
```

I'm wanting it to show the page.title and have the class of h1, but the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
<%= @page.title, class: "h1" %>
```

Anyone got any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to place it in a div for it to have a class applied to it. Thankfully Rails has a content_tag method that would do the job for you:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, @page.title, class: "h1") %>
```

That would output :

```
<div class="h1">Your title</div>
```

See the docs for more info on that method.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Update:

You can nest content within the content_tag like so:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: "h1") do %>
  <%= @page.title %> 
  <div>More stuff</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works, I'm using Bootstrap's pull-right helper for the created_at text which I'd like to be in line with the h1 tag, when I've changed my code for the new content_tag it seems to have pushed the created_at text down a bit, any ideas?

    `<%= content_tag(:div, @page.title, class: "h1") %><p class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on <%= @page.created_at.to_formatted_s :long %></p><br /><hr />
          <p><%= simple_format @page.body %></p>`

Comment: Can you update your question with that code? It's hard to read. I'm not sure I understand what you are saying about how it looks though, it simply applied the class we gave it. Should the other content be nested in the same div?

Comment: Yeah I think the other content should be nested in the same div (basically the <p> and the <span>), is there a way to do that? I can update the question if needed after this comment, thanks again.

Comment: I'm off out now, if this works please accept the answer otherwise I'll reply again in about 30-45 minutes when I'm home.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for being a bit of a newb, didn't think it would be so simple, guess I need to do more research!

Comment: It's all good I'm happy to help, that is what stackoverflow is for!! We were all new to Rails at one stage!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you could just use:

```
<div class="h1">
  <%= @page.title %>
</div>
```